# Sitecore Analytics tracking click events

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-analytics

In a project I am working on tracking click events is done by the following code:

```cs
var goal = new PageEventItem(goalItem);

var eventRow = Tracker.Current.Interaction.CurrentPage.Register(goal);
eventRow.DataKey = ID;
eventRow.Data = NAME;
eventRow.Text = DATA;
```

This will be recorded to the interactions table on MongoDB, What I need know is to create a report that display these registered data? so my question is how I can read these data from MongoDb?

Answer (score 1):

Approach to build reports on data directly from MongoDB will not work well on big amount of records.

You should take a look in a direction [how to aggregate your data in Reporting DB and build report using it](http://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/xDB/reports/extending-experience-analytics-reports/).

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to look at the live data in MongoDb you could try using a third party tool like SlamData - http://slamdata.com/get-slamdata/slamdata-for-mongodb/

This would also give you the ability to produce charts from your MongoDb data. However the data wouldn't be available from within the Sitecore shell.

If you can wait for the data to be aggregated then go with Antons suggestion below.